# Is it possible to make P2P applications work behind CGNATs?

Tags: networking, nat

I've been thinking about making a pure-blooded P2P communication system, without any servers in the middle. Made a prototype on sockets that works locally.

But then it turned out that my provider uses a carrier grade NAT. And actually, all providers in my country use it. I called them, and they told me that they're blocking all inbound ports and the only way to open them is to buy a static IP. Also, they don't use IPV6.

Sounds like the end of the story. But if this is the case, how do, say, multiplayer game servers work then? Obviously they'll have to send me data over some port, which supposedly should be blocked by the provider. And in general, is it possible to establish P2P connections (at least short-lived) if both clients are behind a NAT/CGNAT?

Answer (score 2):

Carrier-grade NAT usually prevents the clients from using port forwarding.
It may be possible to establish P2P connections when both clients are behind
CGNAT by using their respective IP addresses.
This depends on whether the ISP permits traffic based on IP addresses. Some
block such traffic as spam and may even go as far as banning the user's IP.

You should first check out your ISP's policy as regarding using IP addresses
inside its network.

Pure P2P systems can work when connections are allowed inside the ISP's network.
Once the client manages to contact any one initial node, it receives from that node
the list of other known nodes. By contacting these other nodes, it enlarges
and prunes its list in a dynamic manner, and will pass it further on throughout the
network.

NAT has no impact on the flow direction of the data because connections are
bi-directional once they are established.
Each side of a pair of nodes can initiate a connection and also to accept one
initiated by another node.
The only problem is that of finding the initial connection.

There are many other methods used by P2P systems for a node to connect itself.
You will find a list of them in Wikipedia
[NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal).

The success of joining P2P depends on finding at least one node to start the process.
In your case, I can think of several methods:

- Keep the nodes list in a well-known and accessible place,
  for example on Google Drive
- Use a non-standard port and scan the network
  (dangerous, as your ISP may black-list your node)
- Keep one central node on a known address, for example using a static IP or
  a rented server
- Use
  [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)
  for the central node to announce itself dynamically.

Comment: The "policy regarding using IP addresses". Could you please tell me more? How is traffic going around in the ISP's network if not using IP addresses?

Comment: Every ISP keeps track on the internal traffic inside its network, meaning traffic between nodes inside the network, in addition to traffic to/from its gateways. This is an important tool for locating spammers, hackers or just infected zombie computers, or for keeping usage info. In many cases, the action taken is automatic, warning or banning, requiring contacting Support to undo. This is why I suggest contacting Support before, to avoid trouble. This may also depend on how active is the P2P network. Low volumes may go undetected.

Comment: So basically, the answer is "If it's possible or not depends on how exactly your ISP implemented their CGNAT?"

Comment: It's possible depending on your ISP's restrictions. Internal CGNAT connections should work if unrestricted, the only problem being finding the assigned IP addresses.